# gunicorn uvicorn worker.py how to honor limit_concurrency setting

Tags: concurrency, gunicorn, fastapi, uvicorn, concurrency-limits

FastAPI uses gunicorn to launch uvicorn workers as described in https://www.uvicorn.org/settings/

However gunicorn does not allow to launch uvicorn with custom settings as also mentiond in https://github.com/encode/uvicorn/issues/343

The issue suggested to override the config_kwargs in the source file like https://github.com/encode/uvicorn/blob/master/uvicorn/workers.py

We tried it but uvicorn is not honoring the setting `limit_concurrency` in multiple uvicorn files in the source:

https://github.com/encode/uvicorn/blob/master/uvicorn/workers.py

```
# fail

        config_kwargs = {
            "app": None,
            "log_config": None,
            "timeout_keep_alive": self.cfg.keepalive,
            "timeout_notify": self.timeout,
            "callback_notify": self.callback_notify,
            "limit_max_requests": self.max_requests, "limit_concurrency": 10000,
            "forwarded_allow_ips": self.cfg.forwarded_allow_ips,
        }
```

https://github.com/encode/uvicorn/blob/master/uvicorn/main.py

```
# fail

    kwargs = {
        "app": app,
        "host": host,
        "port": port,
        "uds": uds,
        "fd": fd,
        "loop": loop,
        "http": http,
        "ws": ws,
        "lifespan": lifespan,
        "env_file": env_file,
        "log_config": LOGGING_CONFIG if log_config is None else log_config,
        "log_level": log_level,
        "access_log": access_log,
        "interface": interface,
        "debug": debug,
        "reload": reload,
        "reload_dirs": reload_dirs if reload_dirs else None,
        "workers": workers,
        "proxy_headers": proxy_headers,
        "forwarded_allow_ips": forwarded_allow_ips,
        "root_path": root_path,
        "limit_concurrency": 10000,
        "backlog": backlog,
        "limit_max_requests": limit_max_requests,
        "timeout_keep_alive": timeout_keep_alive,
        "ssl_keyfile": ssl_keyfile,
        "ssl_certfile": ssl_certfile,
        "ssl_version": ssl_version,
        "ssl_cert_reqs": ssl_cert_reqs,
        "ssl_ca_certs": ssl_ca_certs,
        "ssl_ciphers": ssl_ciphers,
        "headers": list([header.split(":") for header in headers]),
        "use_colors": use_colors,
    }
```

How can uvicorn be forced to honor this setting? We are still getting 503 errors from the FastAPI

-------UPDATE-----------
the gunicorn setting `--worker-connections 1000` still causes 503 when making 100 parallel requests that are distributed to many workers.

However, I believe it is a bit more complicated issue: our API endpoint does a lot of heavy workload, usually takses 5 seconds to complete.

Stress test with 2 cores, 2 workers:

- A. 100+ concurrent requests, endpoint heavy load --worker-connections 1
- B. 100+ concurrent requests, endpoint heavy load --worker-connections 1000
- C. 100+ concurrent requests, endpoint low     load --worker-connections 1
- D. 100+ concurrent requests, endpoint low     load --worker-connections 1000

Both experiments A und B yielded 503 responses, so assuming the worker-connections setting does work, too many simulatenous connections seem to not cause our 503 errors.

We are puzzled about this behavior, because we expect gunicorn/uvicorn to queue the work and not throw 503 errors.

Comment: Very interested to know whether you resolved your 503 errors in the end, if so what combination of concurrency and backlog settings did you find worked best?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From the [gunicorn doc](https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/settings.html?highlight=worker_connections#worker-connections)

> **`worker-connections`**
>
> The maximum number of simultaneous clients.

and from [uvicorn doc](https://www.uvicorn.org/settings/)

> **`limit-concurrency`**
>
> Maximum number of concurrent connections or tasks to allow, before issuing HTTP 503 responses.

According to this info, both settings variable doing the same thing. So

```
uvicorn --limit-concurrency 100 application:demo_app
```

is almost same as

```
gunicorn --worker-connections 100 -k uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker application:demo_app
```

**Note:** I haven't done any *real test* on this, please do correct me if I am wrong.

---

Also, you can set **`limit-concurrency`** (or **`limit_concurrency`**) by subclassing the **`uvicorn.workers.UvicornWorker`** class

```
from uvicorn.workers import UvicornWorker


class CustomUvicornWorker(UvicornWorker):
    CONFIG_KWARGS = {
        "loop": "uvloop",
        "http": "httptools",
        "limit_concurrency": 100
    }
```

and now use this `CustomUvicornWorker` with `gunicorn` command as,

```
gunicorn -k path.to.custom_worker.CustomUvicornWorker application:demo_app
```

**Note:** you can inspect `self.config.limit_concurrency` in  `CustomUvicornWorker` class to ensure the value has been set correctly.

Comment: thanks for this! the gunicorn --worker-connections 1000 did not have any impact, I am still getting the 503 when I make many parallel requests. 

However our API endpoint does a lot of heavy workload, usually takses 5 seconds to complete. Yet we must do stress tests do see what happens if 100 customers do this request at the same time. This behavior with 503 response happens

Comment: I am not sure why that happe d to you, but, you can try three solutions. 1st, 2nd and combination of 1st and 2nd.

Comment: Yeah, I am not sure, if the 503 is due to concurrent connections, or other resource overload. I will also try the CustomUvicornWorker approach and test it

Comment: did you resolve this?

Comment: For gunicorn with uvicorn class worker-connections has no affect per documentation 

https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/settings.html#worker-connections
The maximum number of simultaneous clients.
This setting only affects the gthread, eventlet and gevent worker types.